# How should I model a nested comment thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Hi
I'm implementing a forum with nested post threads (reddit style)
threads and comments can be voted on.
threads can be tagged
threads have titles, comment don't
my views will usually need to generate only a subset of 3 levels of the whole comment tree.

i'm wondering if I should create a separate and table model for threads, or use only table where root = 0 if it's a thread record

in the latter option i'm thinking of creating a tabless model which will represent a thread (the id will be the id of the root comment

what will be the easiest way to implement it ?

Edit:

this is what i'm thinking about the second option. what relations should thread and post have ? should thread be a resource?

```
class Thread 
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :root_post_id, :depth
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  #belongs_to :thread ?????

  acts_as_tree

  acts_as_taggable_on :topics 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement is to have both the thread and replies in the same table.

```
ID | THREADID
```

The ID field can be auto generated. The THREADID field takes the ID of the thread post which will always be the first post in a thread and all other replies will inherit that same ID.

Therefore a root post is one where the ID == THREAD and replies are those where ID != THREADID.